# Semantic UI React : How to Hide Suggested Text from Search Box

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using Semantic UI React , I want to remove suggested text from search box . I am new to Semantic UI React , I will be very thankful if someone help me to remove suggested Text . Please see an attachment . 
[image]

**Code**

```
import { Search } from 'semantic-ui-react';
<Search placeholder={"Search by Name, Email , Phone , Website"} />
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Jon! What do you mean by "suggested text"? Do you mean the autocomplete text that the browser itself suggests?

Comment: @Tholle , Thank you for your comment . I got an answer . Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
<Search placeholder={"Search by Name, Email , Phone , Website"} showNoResults={false} />
```

This with no source or api should do the trick.